# How to incorporate Quick Sort method in GUI?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, loops, quicksort

I have my lovely little quick sort method ready to go, but I am unsure how to incorporate into a GUI (this will be my first GUI) and GUI do not like public statics and what-not...

So any ideas/know-how one to do a quick sort in a GUI without the publics etc would be amazing!

```
private void sortNumbersButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    

public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a[]={23,44,1,2009,2,88,123,7,999,1040,88};
        quickSort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
        System.out.println(a);
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    }

    public static void quickSort(int[] a, int p, int r)
    {
        if(p<r)
        {
            int q=partition(a,p,r);
            quickSort(a,p,q);
            quickSort(a,q+1,r);
        }
    }

    private static int partition(int[] a, int p, int r) {

        int x = a[p];
        int i = p-1 ;
        int j = r+1 ;

        while (true) {
            i++;
            while ( i< r && a[i] < x)
                i++;
            j--;
            while (j>p && a[j] > x)
                j--;

            if (i < j)
                swap(a, i, j);
            else
                return j;
        }
    }

    private static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Comment: So any ideas/know-how one to do a quick sort in a GUI without the publics etc would be AMAZING! == use JTable

Comment: Most of your text was useless and distracted from the question; please only include text that is relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

One simple option is to present your items in a [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html). Here's a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

Nothing prevents you from using a static method in a GUI application.